# React Pass function to child's child component

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I want to pass a function from parent to child's child component, but showing up as 'undefined'

I understand how to pass function from parent to child:

```
class Child extends Component {
  render() {
        <div onClick={this.props.passedFunction}></div>
    }
}

class Parent extends Component {
    passedFunction = () => {}
    render() {
      <Child passedFunction={this.passedFunction}/>
    }
}
```

[(Reference: past question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407785/react-pass-function-to-child-component)

But how do I properly pass down to the GrandChild in this:

```
class GranChild extends Component {
    render() {
        <div onClick={this.props.passedFunction}></div>
    }
}

class Child extends Component {
    render() {
        <GranChild passedFunction={this.passedFunction}/>
    }
}

class Parent extends Component {
    passedFunction = () => {}
    render() {
      <Child passedFunction={this.passedFunction}/>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refactor your child function to this:

```
class Child extends Component {
render() {
    <GranChild passedFunction={this.props.passedFunction}/>
}
```

}

Comment: I tried this and using chrome react dev tools the props on the GranChild component are passedFunction: undefined